# Cannot restart Strapi after making changes to Content Types (using SQLite)

Tags: sqlite, strapi

I have followed the quickstart setup for Strapi, which as I understand sets up an SQLite Database. I created one collection type (painting) which worked without problems, but whenever I try to add a new one or make changes to the existing one the server does not restart and I receive the following error output in my console:

[2022-05-23 16:53:16.323] error: CREATE TABLE `_knex_temp_alter889` (`id` integer not null primary key autoincrement PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, `title` varchar(255) NULL, `artist` varchar(255) NULL, `created_at` datetime NULL, `updated_at` datetime NULL, `published_at` datetime NULL, `created_by_id` integer NULL, `updated_by_id` integer NULL, CONSTRAINT `paintings_created_by_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`created_by_id`) REFERENCES `admin_users` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL, CONSTRAINT `paintings_updated_by_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`updated_by_id`) REFERENCES `admin_users` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL, CONSTRAINT `paintings_created_by_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`created_by_id`) REFERENCES `admin_users` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL, CONSTRAINT `paintings_updated_by_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`updated_by_id`) REFERENCES `admin_users` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL) - table "_knex_temp_alter889" has more than one primary key
SqliteError: CREATE TABLE `_knex_temp_alter889` (`id` integer not null primary key autoincrement PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, `title` varchar(255) NULL, `artist` varchar(255) NULL, `created_at` datetime NULL, `updated_at` datetime NULL, `published_at` datetime NULL, `created_by_id` integer NULL, `updated_by_id` integer NULL, CONSTRAINT `paintings_created_by_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`created_by_id`) REFERENCES `admin_users` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL, CONSTRAINT `paintings_updated_by_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`updated_by_id`) REFERENCES `admin_users` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL, CONSTRAINT `paintings_created_by_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`created_by_id`) REFERENCES `admin_users` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL, CONSTRAINT `paintings_updated_by_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`updated_by_id`) REFERENCES `admin_users` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL) - table "_knex_temp_alter889" has more than one primary key

Deleting the changes I made in my content-types files is currently the only way I have of getting the server to run again. How do I fix this?

Comment: Try to format the error message you are providing in a better way, this is very user unfriendly.

Answer (score 0):

So, I ended up creating a new project. Problem seems to have been that I added a field named 'ID', which I assume messed everything up because it conflicted with the automatically assigned ID-System.

Comment: Is there a way to reverse this?